# How to filter my query and remove duplicates?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, where-clause

I'm trying to query all records from the following table, but without duplication, as follows:

| ID | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | Green |
| 2 | apple | red |
| 3 | apple | Yeelow |
| 4 | banana | green |
| 5 | banana | yellow |
| 6 | grape | green |
| 7 | grape | red |
| 8 | grape | white |

Result required:

| ID | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | Green |
| 2 |  | red |
| 3 |  | Yeelow |
| 4 | banana | green |
| 5 |  | yellow |
| 6 | grape | green |
| 7 |  | red |
| 8 |  | white |

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: I am using Android studio with  "DB Browser For SQLite"

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is usually better done in the application layer than in the database.  But you can do it in the database:

```
select id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name order by id) = 1
             then name
        end) as name,
       color
from t
order by name, id;
```

This is enumerating the rows for each name in `id` order and only showing the name for the first one.

Very importantly, the outer `order by` is consistent with the window frame specification -- without the outer `order by`, the results could be in any order.  And your results require a particular ordering.

Comment: Done perfectly when executed in "DB Browser For SQLite" but when implemented in Android Studio the 'C' in 'Case' is underlined in red and the following message occurred. Err: Select , VALUES or WITH expected , got 'CASE'... As if 'Case' is not supported in Android studio

Comment: @DanyDamianos . . . That is really strange.  `CASE` is standard SQL and has been part of SQLite for as long as I can remember.